# Trying to make a function to call rock-paper-scissor-game but showing error invalid command name ".!button8"

Tags: python, tkinter

##importing libraries
i defined click here because i have used it globally in later functions

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import random
click=True
```

##making function
this function is called when i will click on buttons
i have inserted images in button and want to configure them

```
def function(userchoice):
    global click 

    global pbutton
    global rbutton
    global sbutton


    global handrock
    global handpaper
    global handscissor

    global rock
    global paper
    global scissor

    global win 
    global lose
    global tie

    global score_win
    global score_lose

    choice=["rock","paper","scissor"]
    compchoice=random.choice(choice)

    if click==True:
         if userchoice==compchoice:
                pbutton.config(image=tie)
                rbutton.config(image=tie)
                sbutton.config(image=tie)
                click=False
         elif userchoice=="rock" and compchoice=="scissor":
                pbutton.config(image=rock)
                rbutton.config(image=win)
                sbutton.config(image=scissor)
                click=False
                score_win=score_win+1
                marks(score_win,win)
        elif userchoice=="paper" and compchoice=="rock":
                pbutton.config(image=paper)
                rbutton.config(image=win)
                sbutton.config(image=rock)
                click=False
                score_win=score_win+1
                marks(score_win,win)
        elif userchoice=="scissor" and compchoice=="paper":
                pbutton.config(image=paper)
                rbutton.config(image=win)
                sbutton.config(image=scissor)
                click=False
                score_win=score_win+1
                marks(score_win,win)
        elif compchoice=="rock" and userchoice=="scissor":
                pbutton.config(image=rock)
                rbutton.config(image=lose)
                sbutton.config(image=scissor)
                click=False
                score_lose=score_lose+1
                marks(score_lose,lose)
        elif compchoice=="paper" and userchoice=="rock":
                pbutton.config(image=paper)
                rbutton.config(image=lose)
                sbutton.config(image=rock)
                click=False
                score_lose=score_lose+1
                marks(score_lose,lose)
        elif compchoice=="scissor" and userchoice=="paper":
                pbutton.config(image=paper)
                rbutton.config(image=lose)
                sbutton.config(image=scissor)
                click=False
                score_lose=score_lose+1
                marks(score_lose,lose)
    else:
        pbutton.config(image=handpaper)
        rbutton.config(image=handrock)
        sbutton.config(image=handscissor)
        click=True
```

making funtion marks

```
def marks(m,image):
    global score_win
    global score_lose

    if m==5:
       global pbutton
       global rbutton
       global sbutton
       pbutton.config(image=image)
       rbutton.config(image=image)
       sbutton.config(image=image)
       score_win=0
       score_lose=0
```

making function start

```
def start():
    r=Tk()
    handrock=PhotoImage(file="D:/handrock.gif")
    handpaper=PhotoImage(file="D:/handpaper.gif")
    handscissor=PhotoImage(file="D:/handscissor.gif")

    rock=PhotoImage(file="D:/rock.gif")
    paper=PhotoImage(file="D:/paper.gif")
    scissor=PhotoImage(file="D:/scissor.gif")

    lose=PhotoImage(file="D:/lose.gif")
    win=PhotoImage(file="D:/win.gif")
    tie=PhotoImage(file="D:/tie.gif")

    score_win=0
    score_lose=0

    pbutton=Button(r,image=handpaper,command=lambda:function("paper"))
    rbutton=Button(r,image=handrock,command=lambda:function("rock"))
    sbutton=Button(r,image=handscissor,command=lambda:function("scissor"))

    pbutton.grid(row=0,column=0)
    rbutton.grid(row=0,column=1)
    sbutton.grid(row=0,column=2)

    r.mainloop()
```

calling start

```
start()
```

error====

```
Exception in Tkinter callbace
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "<ipython-input-75-a4db1c349196>", line 27, in <lambda>
rbutton=Button(frps,image=handrock,command=lambda:function("rock"))
File "<ipython-input-76-1861da8b882c>", line 78, in function
pbutton.config(image=handpaper)
File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1637, in configure
return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1627, in _configure
self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!button8"
```

I tried declaring buttons global so that i can configure them in later functions but it didnt work

this code was working fine when i used code in start function as main code and defined function and marks as function but actually i was making a combined game in tkinter where i need to call  this game when user clicks on the given button but because the buttons declared in the start function are local to that function only so i cannot configure then in another function so declared then global but still error is no resolved

Comment: you have to use `global pbutton` in `start()` . At this moment you create local `pbutton` in `start()` and other function can't use it.

Comment: BTW: there is bug in `PhotoImage` which removes image from memory when you assign `PhotoImage` to local variable in function. You will have to assign all `PhotoImage` to global variables or to other objects. See `Note` at the end of page [PhotoImage](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112023229/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

Comment: so after defining pbutton , rbutton ,sbutton , I have to make them global in start itself??

Comment: also I have made my  images global in the fuc function(userchoice) do i need to define it global in start only??

Comment: you have to use `global variable ` in function when you use `variable = ...` in this function (and want to access `variable` also in other function). So you have to use `global` for images in `start()` because in `start()` you use `rock = ...`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `global` in `start()`

```
def start():
    global pbutton
    global rbutton
    global sbutton
```

You need `global` when you assign (`=`)` value to variable. It inform function that it has to assign value to external/global variable instead of creating local variable.

Frankly, you don't need `global pbutton` when you do `pbutton.config(...)` but only when you do `pbutton = ...`

---

**BTW:**

There is bug in `PhotoImage` which removes image from memory when you assign `PhotoImage` to local variable in function. You will have to assign all `PhotoImage` to global variables or to other objects. See `Note` at the end of page [PhotoImage](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112023229/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)